# Making custom layouts in LaTeX

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I want to create a layout like this sketch i made:

[image: Layout]

But I can't seem to crack this one. I am pretty new to LaTeX, and have done a lot of searching without any luck.

The idea is that like a chapter or a section or whatever will be one file, and then the person working on that document only has to write his text and not a lot of code, and insert the picture references in the bottom of the file.

The reason I am trying to make this is that I work in a group at my university, where a lot of people don't seem to have the time or interest to learn the basics of LaTeX, but everyone wants to work in it.

If the answer is allready out there somewhere, I am sorry to ask again — and I really hope soneone can help me out here!

Comment: Did you have a look at the [`tufte`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex) class? It could solve your problem and it has very good typography.

Comment: The `ccaption` package documentation has an example with a marginal paragraph and a legend. You should be able to change the text in the paragraph to a picture.

Comment: I think this is what you were looking for http://www.latextemplates.com/template/tufte-style-book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are new to LaTeX, let me explain what I think is more difficult and what seems easy.

You want to put figures and probably tabulars, quotes and pictures into the margin. You get into trouble, if not all content, which you wish to have in the margin of a certain page, can be printed before the pagebreak. What you need is that the margin column with your content will be carried forward in the margin column of the next page.

This was -- as far as I know -- a real problem before version 3.12 of KOMA-script. But maybe the memoir-class as well had a solution, I don't know that.

With v. 3.12 of KOMA-script you can do something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel, scrlayer-notecolumn, setspace, booktabs, ragged2e,
  perpage, xcolor, xspace, blindtext}



%%%%% Marginnotes with scrlayer-notecolumn, xcolor and perpage
%% We have to reduce the width of the text using addmargin:
%% \begin{addmargin}[0cm]{1cm}

 \DeclareNewNoteColumn[font=\sffamily\footnotesize\RaggedRight, width=3cm, 
 position=\oddsidemargin+1in+\textwidth-1cm+\marginparsep]{randnot}

\newcounter{Rnnr}
\MakePerPage{Rnnr}% Counterreset every new page
% with package perpage, there also is zref-perpage
\renewcommand{\theRnnr}{\alph{Rnnr}}% print letters as anchors
\newcommand{\Anm}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{Rnnr}%
\textcolor{red}{\textsuperscript{\textit{\theRnnr}}}% Anker im Text
  \makenote[randnot]{% Randnotiz
    \textsuperscript{\theRnnr}#1\xspace}} %%Randnotentext
%%%%% \renewcommand{\Anm[1]}{}
%%%% deletes Anm


\begin{document}
\begin{addmargin}[0pt]{1cm}
  \blindtext\Anm{%
    \protect\begin{tabular}{lr}
      Januar & 1\\
      Februar & 2\\
      März & 3\\
    \protect\end{tabular}
}


  \blindtext

\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

There is a lot to explain, but if you are interested, please read the new KOMA-script documentation (`texdoc komascript` on the commandline with texlive).

I defined the command `\Anm` (German abbrevation for »Anmerkung« = annotation), which makes a kind of sidenote. To prevent mixing the anchors in the text with footnotemarks, the mark is a letter, not a number. You can't put floats into this kind of sidenote.

Headers and footers are easy, use the package `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of scrpage2.

Comment: It dosent seem like I can figure out how to make the script you made run. I use Texmaker and MiKTeX, if that is any help.

Comment: You need to update KOMA-script, see here: http://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex

Comment: I have now made sure I have all the packages, and they are up to date (KOMA-script version 3.12), but I still cant run the script. Seems like it is the "scrlayer-notecolumn" that makes all the trouble. Any idears?

Comment: @BullDodga Please provide the error message and the log. The file compiles on my notebook without any error.

Comment: There is no error message but "error" sadly.
For the log file, follow this link: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=4DC345A5D9D2320E!390&authkey=!ACiwyucoFtg9I8g&ithint=file%2c.log

Comment: @BullDodga Your update was not successful, as you can see in warnings like `"LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 53, version
               `2013/03/05' of package scrkbase,
               but only version
               `2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)'
               is available.
"`. If you write `\listfiles` to the beginning of your file (before `\documentclass`), you can check in the log, whether all files from KOMA-script are version 3.12. Maybe you made several attempts to install it and that left something somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

**a chapter or a section or whatever will be one file**:

For that you can use `\include{the name of the file}` command. Here what we do is, the code to written separately is done by creating a new "some name".tex file and adding it to the include command and this must be in the same folder where the original .tex file is present else you need to specify the full path and secondly you need to put in appropriate place after the `\begin{document}` command.